How to tell gcc that my source contains Q_OBJECT?
I am trying to compile an object file, for C++/Qt; but I receive the warning below, stating that there is no "Q_OBJECT" in my code.
Do I miss something? (my CMakeList.txt contains set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON))
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
class TestObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
       TestObject();
  static TestObject *get() {
    static auto *handler = new TestObject;
    return handler;
  }
};

#include "testobject.h"
#include "testobject.moc"


TestObject::TestObject() {
}

AutoMoc warning
---------------
"SRC:/modules/testobject.cpp"
includes the moc file "testobject.moc", but does not contain a Q_OBJECT, Q_GADGET, Q_NAMESPACE, Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT or Q_GADGET_EXPORT macro.


You don't usually include a file named "testobject.moc", naming convention is "moc_testobject.h".
Does the file "testobject.moc" exist at all?

It is rather messy for me. As the error message shows, automoc finds that I wanted to include that file, and in the previous line it should find the include where Q_Object is uses. Stiil, it says I do not use Q_Object. The docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/moc.html  explicitly mentions foo.moc. I would not work with moc, it it would work as discribed.

Actually, I receive message "undefined reference to`vtable for TestObject'"; this is what I am checking why.
